# How to calculate the area of polygon overlap in R?

Tags: r, overlay, polygon, intersection

Does anyone know how to calculate the area in common between 2 or more polygons in R? I would like to have the output of such a calculation be the coordinates of a new polygon for that area of overlap.
Cheers

Answer (score 13, accepted):

EDIT: these days I would use the 'intersect', 'cover', 'erase', 'union' and related functions in the 'raster' package. They do the hard work to keep the top-level object and attributes.

ORIG: 
You could use the `rgeos` package with its `gIntersection` function. Successive calls between pairs and resulting intersections will get you there. See

```
library(rgeos)
?gIntersection
```

You will need to get into the structure of "SpatialPolygons" in the `sp` package to get the final coordinates. See the vignette("sp").

Comment: Thanks for the tips. they steered me in the right direction. Will have to try out some other packages, but PBSmapping has a pretty straightforward way to do what I needed:  library(PBSmapping)
p1 <- data.frame(PID=rep(1, 4), POS=1:4, X=c(1,1,6,6), Y=c(1,3,3,1))
p2 <- data.frame(PID=rep(2, 5), POS=1:5, X=c(4,4,8,8,6), Y=c(2,4,4,2,1))
p3 <- joinPolys(p1,p2)

plot(1,1,ylim=c(0,10),xlim=c(0,10), t="n")
polygon(p1$X, p1$Y, border=2)
polygon(p2$X, p2$Y)
polygon(p3$X, p3$Y, col=rgb(0,0,1,0.2))

Answer (score 10):

Just thought I would add the solution that I eventually used - the `joinPolys` function from the `PBSmapping` package.

#### Example:

```
library(PBSmapping)
p1 <- data.frame(PID=rep(1, 4), POS=1:4, X=c(1,1,6,6), Y=c(1,3,3,1))
p2 <- data.frame(PID=rep(2, 5), POS=1:5, X=c(4,4,8,8,6), Y=c(2,4,4,2,1))
p3 <- joinPolys(p1,p2)
x11()
par(mar=c(3,3,1,1))
plot(1,1,ylim=c(0,5),xlim=c(0,9), t="n", xlab="", ylab="")
polygon(p1$X, p1$Y, border=2)
polygon(p2$X, p2$Y)
polygon(p3$X, p3$Y, col=rgb(0,0,1,0.2))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Marc in the box. I was searching for a answer to my question: How to calculate the non-overlapping area between two center aligned arbitrary polygon (with no holes) using R? It seems to me that your question is similar to me (though I want to have "complement area"), but I could not solved it. I want the area (scalar unit). Could you please help me in this direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mark, amazing - exactly what I need. Thanks for posting your solution!