# Calculating the percent overlap of two polygons in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, geojson, topojson

Here's the problem: I have geoJSON and topoJSON files that give me the polygons for Census block groups and voting precincts. I'm trying to see by how much a given Census block group overlaps with a given precinct.

I've seen a couple examples of what I'm after in other languages—i.e. [R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977074/how-to-calculate-the-area-of-polygon-overlap-in-r) and in some GIS tools—but I'm trying to write this as a Node.js script. A few questions:

1. Is there an NPM module (I've done a fair amount of Googling, but I haven't found one) that can spit out the percent overlap?
2. Is there an algorithm, or an exmaple written in another language, that I should know about (I've looked, but I haven't the foggiest where to begin) and that I could port to JavaScript?
3. Failing these, can someone explain to me how I *would* go about thinking about creating an algorithm for this?

In the end, the final product would look something like this—imagining that I have arrays of precincts and blockgroups, and each one is an object with a geometry property that contains the polygon data for the precinct or block group, and also imagining that I have a function called `overlap` that, when passed two polygons spits out the percent overlap:

```
// Iterate over each precinct.
_.each( precincts, function ( precinct ) {

    // Iterate over each blockgroup.
    _.each( blockgroups, function ( blockgroup ) {

        // Get the overlap for the current precinct and blockgroup.
        var o = overlap( precinct.geometry, blockgroup.geometry );

        // If they overlap at all...
        if ( o > 0 ) {

            // ...Add information about the overlap to the precinct.
            precinct.overlaps.push({
                blockgroup: blockgroup.id,
                overlap: o
            });

        }

    }

}
```

(I've seen [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/turf-overlaps), but that only gives *if* the polygons overlap, not by how much they do.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compute the overlapping percentage

1. Compute the intersection of the two polygons

   ```
   Intersection = intersect(Precinct, Block)
   ```
2. Divide the area of Intersection by the area of the parent polygon of interest.

   ```
   Overlap = area(Intersection) / area(Parent)
   ```
3. It is a little unclear what you mean by the percent overlap. The parent polygon could be one of several possibilities

   ```
   a) area(Intersection) / area(Precinct)

   b) area(Intersection) / area(Block)

   c) area(Intersection) / area(Precinct union Block)
   ```

As for a javascript library, this one seems to have what you need [Intersection.js](http://www.kevlindev.com/gui/math/intersection/index.htm)

There's also the [JSTS Topology Suite](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts) which can do geospatial processing in JavaScript. See Node.js examples [here](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts/tree/master/examples/nodejs).

Comment: This looks great. Thank you! And you're totally right that it's unclear what I meant by percent overlap. I meant something b).

Answer (score 8):

[turf-intersect](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf-intersect) takes two polygons and returns a polygon representing the intersection.

[geojson-area](https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-area) takes a polygon and returns the area in square meters.

```
npm install turf
npm install geojson-area

var turf = require('turf');
var geojsonArea = require('geojson-area');

var poly1 = {
"type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [[
      [-122.801742, 45.48565],
      [-122.801742, 45.60491],
      [-122.584762, 45.60491],
      [-122.584762, 45.48565],
      [-122.801742, 45.48565]
    ]]
  }
}
var poly2 = {
"type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [[
      [-122.520217, 45.535693],
      [-122.64038, 45.553967],
      [-122.720031, 45.526554],
      [-122.669906, 45.507309],
      [-122.723464, 45.446643],
      [-122.532577, 45.408574],
      [-122.487258, 45.477466],
      [-122.520217, 45.535693]
    ]]
  }
}

var intersection = turf.intersect(poly1, poly2);

var area_intersection = geojsonArea.geometry(intersection.geometry);
var area_poly1        = geojsonArea.geometry(poly1.geometry);

var percent_poly1_covered_by_poly2 = (area_intersection / area_poly1)*100;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do spatial overlaps with [Turf js](http://turfjs.org/). It has the features of JSTS (and more), but is very modular.

Comment: Not useful if you do not describe how to do it.

Comment: the documentation is very clear.